# VBA: Open chat from html telegram website

Tags: html, vba, excel

The objetive is to open the first telegram chat from the website: https://web.telegram.org/#/im and see the content. In my case would be "Telegram" chat as the image below.
[image: Telegram image]

I got this code from another question and tried to edit it for the need and it seems to perform the click but does not show the conversation.

```
Sub Telegram()

 'Open website
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://web.telegram.org/"
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    'Wait till page charge
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    'Click on first telegram chat
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("im_dialog_peer")(0).Click

End Sub
```

HTML code according to inspect element:

```
<div class="im_dialog_message_wrap">

    <div class="im_dialog_peer">
      <span my-peer-link="dialogMessage.peerID" verified="true">Telegram <i class="icon-verified"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch="dialogMessage.typing ? 'typing' : (!dialogMessage.unreadCount &amp;&amp; dialogMessage.draft ? 'draft' : (dialogMessage.deleted ? 'deleted' : 'message'))">

      <!---->

      <!---->

      <!---->

      <!----><div ng-switch-when="message" class="im_dialog_message" style="">
        <span ng-switch="dialogMessage.peerID > 0 || dialogMessage.fromID < 0">
          <!----><span ng-switch-when="true">
            <!---->
          </span><!---->
          <!---->
        </span>

        <span my-short-message="dialogMessage"><!----><!----><!----><span class="im_short_message_text" ng-if="message.message.length &amp;&amp; (!message.media || message.media._ == 'messageMediaWebPage')" ng-bind-html="message.richMessage">Angel:  Detectamos una conexión a tu cuenta desde un nuevo dispo</span><!----></span>
      </div><!---->
    </div>

  </div>
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName("im_dialog_peer")(0).Click` is the div, I think you need the span inside (not sure, it uses js?). You know the [api](https://core.telegram.org/api)?

Comment: @BitAccesser, i think that the `ng-switch-when` property name indicates that the web app may have been built using `angularJS`

Comment: @jsotola and I am sure seen the same problem, just a few weeks ago. If I rember right, you can call a js-function with IE, but without login I can't see the code. Maybe the api fits better for OP.